# How to set up ruby on Docker - getting nokogiri error

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

My Doc Dockerfile has FROM Ubuntu:18.04

I want to use ruby so i did

```
gem install bundler
```

However when I try to

```
bundle
```

I get an error with nokogiri

```
Installing nokogiri 1.10.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.2/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20190414-288-1mfprtc.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.10.2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.10.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.10.2' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a dependency called `nokogiri` that has external dependency, usually it's libxml and libxslt.

All you need to do is `apt get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev`

Here's a working example of a Ruby `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ruby:2.6.2

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY Gemfile* /usr/src/app/
RUN bundle install -j3

ADD . /usr/src/app

ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]
CMD ["rails", "server"]
```

Comment: It's not working, I am running ruby@3.1.0 with rails@6.0.4.4